# Why in my css grid have extra grid cell in the end?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Why does the last section have extra grid cells when there are only 6 items in my navbar and one of them is in the first row?

[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  margin: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
}

.navbar div {
  background-color: rgb(255, 144, 255);
}

.navbar h1 {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <h1>12345</h1>
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>
    <div class="item4">4</div>
    <div class="item5">5</div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: because of the grid-column:1/-1 on the h1 element making auto-fit behave the same as auto-fill

Comment: so, what should i add/replace to remove those extra grid cells